# Объясните пример из qt Osciloscope

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, qml

Интересует именно момент, каким образом данные которые генерируются, попадают на график, не могу никак понять, зачем там столько дополнительных переменных
да и функции вроде не массив передают.

Главный вопрос и задача в том, что у меня есть массив , который создается рассчитывается и постоянно меняется в С++
теперь я хочу, что бы в моей части с графикой, все эти значения отрисовывались.
Разобрав пример я не понимаю как я могу это сделать

[Сам пример.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-example.html)

Comment: Ссылку в студию!

Comment: @free_ze именно вот этот
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря, от QML я далек, но вижу следующее: есть источник данных `DataSource`, в котором есть ссылка на компонент графика `QQuickView`:

```
QQuickView viewer;
...
DataSource dataSource(&viewer);
viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("dataSource", &dataSource);
```

([main.cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-main-cpp.html))

А потом по событию таймера (60 раз в секунду) мы просим этот источник данных нарисовать новые значения.

```
Timer {
    ...
    interval: 1 / 60 * 1000 // 60 Hz
    ...
    onTriggered: {
        dataSource.update(chartView.series(0));
        dataSource.update(chartView.series(1));
    }
}
```

([ScopeView.qml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-qml-qmloscilloscope-scopeview-qml.html))

Где:

```
void DataSource::update(QAbstractSeries *series)
{
    if (series) {
        QXYSeries *xySeries = static_cast<QXYSeries *>(series);
        m_index++;
        if (m_index > m_data.count() - 1)
            m_index = 0;

        QVector<QPointF> points = m_data.at(m_index);
        // Use replace instead of clear + append, it's optimized for performance
        xySeries->replace(points);
    }
}
```

([DataSource.cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-qmloscilloscope-datasource-cpp.html))

Переменных много, потому что много сущностей)

- `DataSource` - одновременно хранилище данных, их генератор и штука,
  которая умеет добавлять значения в графики.
- `QXYSeries` - сами графики-ломаные (их там два).
- `QQuickView` - холст, на котором графики рисуются.

Остальное - детали интерфейса.

Comment: первая ваша выноска кода, как я понимаю дает доступ для видимости и работы функций ++ в qml??
второй понятно
и третий блок нужно будет внимательно разобрать)
адекватным ли будет такое применение и  использование для рисования риал тайм графиков?

Comment: @СашаТозик Да, хотя я не могу понять, зачем в DataSource инжектится QQuickView, т.к. он не используется явно. 60Гц для вас - это риалтайм или нет?) Строго сказать не могу, ибо с системами реального времени дел не имел (но под тот же QNX Qt собрать вроде как можно). Если же вас интересует просто удобство пользователя, то подойдет, почему нет? Если интерфейс не перегружен, то ощутимых тормозов быть не должно.